# Como identificar o tipo de dado que o usuario digitou num prompt ou input?

Tags: tipagem, prompt

Comecei a estudar JS faz 3 semanas e sou bem aprendiz mesmo...

Minha maior dúuvida atual é que eu não sei um operador ou comando para identificar e condicionar o valor do tipo de dado digitado pelo usuário, exemplo:

```
var userValue = prompt("Digite um valor numérico");

    if(typeof userValue == "string"){
        alert("Você precisa digitar um valor numérico para prosseguir");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        alert("Ok, vamos prosseguir");
        ...codigo...
    }
```

Como podem ver eu utilizei tentei usar o `typeof` para identificar... no caso se for `string` vai retornar falso...

Acontece que qualquer coisa que eu digito no *prompt* ele interpreta como `string`...

Tambem não adianta usar `parseInt` ou `+` no *prompt* porque aí ele sempre interpreta como `number` o valor digitado...

O que eu poderia fazer nesse caso?

Agradeço desde agora a sua atenção ^^

Comment: Um numero sempre pode ser uma string, entao nao ajuda isso o que voce fez. Mas voce sabe que um numero nao tem caracteres nao numericos alem do '.' certo? Isso deve ajudar.

Comment: Agradeço tua resposta, Lucas! Mas, de maneira + objetiva, como deve ficar para se o usuario digitar letras retornar falso e digitar numero dar true?

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer garantir que o que o usuário digitou pode ser tratado como número, as funções `parseInt` e `Number` te ajudam. Se o que o usuário digitou não puder ser convertido para número, você vai obter o valor `NaN`(*not a number*).

Atenção que o parseInt descarta partes não númericas do texto.

Uma forma segura de se validar:

```
var foo = prompt("");
if (Number(foo) == foo) {
    // o input é todo numérico.
} else {
    // o input não é completamente numérico.
}
```

Comment: Certo, o parseInt apenas força a variavel a ser tratada como number...

Não conhecia a função Number, vou estudar + sobre ela.

Valeu pela atenção :D